# Printing a double linked list with const pointer

Tags: c++, c, printing, delete-operator, doubly-linked-list

I don't get why one function does not work. It has something to do with the const pointer.

```
//prints the contents of the list interval [begin,end)
//to the output stream os; values should be separated by spaces
void print(const Node* begin, const Node* end, ostream& os)
{
    Node* current_node = begin;
    do
    {
        os << current_node->value << " ";
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
    while(current_node != end);
    os << endl;
}
```

I am not allowed to change the head of this function.

Will this function will work?

```
//erases the list interval [begin,end)
//attention: this should not erase 'end', see remarks above
void erase(Node* begin, Node* end){
    Node* current_node = begin;
    Node* next_node = begin->next;
    Node* begin_node = begin->prev;
    while(current_node != end){
        next_node->prev = current_node->prev;
        begin_node->next = next_node;
        delete current_node;
        current_node = next_node;
        next_node = current_node->next;
    }
}
```

And here is the struct of the Node

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};
```

Comment: And what's the problem actually? Compiler error, runtime crash, unexpected result? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not right:

```
Node* current_node = begin;
```

Since the type of `begin` is `const Node*`, you need to change the type of `current_node` to `const Node*` for that line to work:

```
const Node* current_node = begin;
```

Regarding your function `erase`, I see some problems:

1. If `begin->prev` is NULL, you will run into problem in the line:

   ```
   begin_node->next = next_node;
   ```
2. Is `end` expected to be NULL? If not, I don't see `end->prev` set to `begin_node` anywhere. Without that, the doubly linked list is broken.

Comment: Is then possible to make this? current_node = current_node->next; And when why is this then possible?

Comment: @SvenBamberger, yes, you can use `current_node = current_node->next;`.

Comment: @R Sahu Ok but why? isn't it also a const?

Comment: @SvenBamberger, the value of a variable of type `const Node*` can be changed by assignment as long as the type of the expression on the RHS can be converted to `const Node*`. Perhaps you are thinking about variables that are declared const, like `const i = 10;`, whose values cannot be changed later.